# d3 js know if an svg shape has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I want to have a toggle button in an svg shape, and scale it down when the button is clicked, then scale up when clicked again, firstly I added a class `collapse` like this. I want to remove the class if it has a class `collapse`

```
g.append("circle")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", radius * 0.4 - 10)
    .attr("fill", color(radius * 0.4 - 10))
    .on("click", (d) ->
      if(hasClass("collapse")) # HOW DO I DO THIS
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Musically_ut's solution is correct, but only supported by last browsers (e.g. Safari 6.0.5 and before won't work, which [is a release of June 5, 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history))

The tricky part here is that the SVG DOM is different to the HTML DOM. So you cannot just use `classList.contains` for older browsers. ([see basic jsfiddle comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/XexwQ/1/) between SVG and HTML)

Here is a [less beautiful] version which works with older browsers. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvFR2/3/))

```
g.append("circle")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", radius * 0.4 - 10)
    .attr("fill", 'black')
    .on('click', function(d){
        this.setAttribute('class', '');
        // or if your element has other classnames as well
        // scan the class names, remove the "collapse" from it and push the new string into class.
        //if(this.className.baseVal.indexOf('collapse')>=0){ … }
    }
   );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList):

```js
g.append("circle")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", radius * 0.4 - 10)
    .attr("fill", color(radius * 0.4 - 10))
    .on("click", (d) ->
      if(this.classList.contains("collapse")) {
        // ...
        // this.classList.remove('collapse')
      } else {
        // ...
        // this.classList.add('collapse')
      }
    )
```

Or jQuery:

```js
g.append("circle")
    .classed("collapse", true)
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", radius * 0.4 - 10)
    .attr("fill", color(radius * 0.4 - 10))
    .on("click", (d) ->
      if($(this).hasClass("collapse")) {
        // ...
      }
    )
```

The `this` inside the call backs refers to the DOM Element.
This is, however, not quite the D3-isque way of doing things. One should save the `collapsed` status on the `data` associated with the node and act on it rather than save the status in the `class` of the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question looks like CoffeeScript rather than pure JavaScript. If that is the case then d3.js way would be:

```
.on "click", ->
  d3.select(this).classed("collapse", false) unless d3.select(this).select(".collapse").empty()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, though it is too simple:

```
enter code hereg.append("circle")
.classed("collapse", true)
.attr("cx", 0)
.attr("cy", 0)
.attr("r", radius * 0.4 - 10)
.attr("fill", color(radius * 0.4 - 10))
.on("click", (d)) {

  var this_ = d3.select(this);

    if(this_.select(".collapse").attr("visibility") == "visible") {

      this_.select(".collapse").attr("visibility", "hidden");

    } else {

      this_.select(".collapse").attr("visibility", "visible");

    }

});
```